# Application has been already initialized. (RuntimeError) when testing a Rails engine with Cucumber and a dummy application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, rails-engines

I just created a new Rails 5.1.4 engine using `rails plugin new <name> --dummy-path=features/dummy --skip-test-unit --mountable`, updated the gemspec/Gemfile file in order to add `cucumber-rails` (1.5.0), `database_cleaner` (1.6.2) and `pg` (0.21.0), and I have updated the `features/support/env.rb` file in order to add:

```
...
# Rails Engine requirements
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../dummy/config/environment.rb', __FILE__)
ENV['RAILS_ROOT'] ||= File.dirname(__FILE__) + '../../dummy'

require 'cucumber/rails'
...
```

but when I run the cucumber command I have the following error:

```
Application has been already initialized. (RuntimeError)
/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/bundle/gems/cucumber-rails-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/rails/application.rb:15:in `initialize!'
/application/features/dummy/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/bundle/gems/cucumber-3.1.0/lib/cucumber/glue/registry_and_more.rb:106:in `load_code_file'
/bundle/gems/cucumber-3.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:147:in `load_file'
/bundle/gems/cucumber-3.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:88:in `block in load_files!'
/bundle/gems/cucumber-3.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:87:in `each'
/bundle/gems/cucumber-3.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:87:in `load_files!'
/bundle/gems/cucumber-3.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:270:in `load_step_definitions'
/bundle/gems/cucumber-3.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:67:in `run!'
/bundle/gems/cucumber-3.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:33:in `execute!'
/bundle/gems/cucumber-3.1.0/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
/bundle/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/bundle/bin/cucumber:23:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:75:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:75:in `kernel_load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:424:in `exec'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:122:in `with_friendly_errors'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:104:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:104:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:75:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:75:in `kernel_load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:424:in `exec'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:122:in `with_friendly_errors'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.0/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:104:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:104:in `<main>'
```

The `features/dummy/config/environment.rb` file looks like the following:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

Everywhere I'm looking people are recommending to add those 3 lines in the `env.rb` file and then it's working so I'm a bit lost.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured out what is the issue after having debugged the cucumber source code.

I was thinking Cucumber was autoloading **only** the files from the `support` folder, but this is actually wrong.

The [`load_step_definitions` method](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/blob/v3.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb#L268) is preparing a list of files to be loaded from the `support_to_load` method output, and from the [`step_defs_to_load` method](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/blob/v3.1.0/lib/cucumber/configuration.rb#L188) which is using the returned list of files from `all_files_to_load` in order to reject all the files from the `support` folder (already listed from the `support_to_load` method).

But [the `all_files_to_load` method](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/blob/v3.1.0/lib/cucumber/configuration.rb#L175) is looking for all the files from the `--require` cucumber option, which is set to `features` out of the box when generating the `cucumber.yml` file so that all the files in the `features` folder are loaded, even the dummy app in this case.

The reason it is working for the others is that they're all creating the dummy app in the `spec/dummy` path while I decided to use `features/dummy` (as I'm not using Rspec in this project).

Looking deeper in the case I found that the `all_files_to_load` method also calls [the `remove_excluded_files_from` method](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/blob/v3.1.0/lib/cucumber/configuration.rb#L273) which allows you to ignore some files when cucumber boots, which is what I want here.

So the 2 possible solutions:

- Moving the dummy app out of the `features` folder
- Sets the `--exclude` flag

I choosed the last option so I have updated the `cucumber.yml` file `default` profile from:

```
default: <%= std_opts %> features
```

to:

```
default: <%= std_opts %> features --exclude dummy
```

And now I no more have this error when running `bundle exec cucumber`.